# How to send data from child directive to parent without shared services/factories?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, data-sharing, angular-services

I have two directives. One is an element and another one is an attribute.

```
<item attr></item>
```

How do I send data from attribute controller to the element controller. Note that a have a few instances of item, thus I can't use shared service because I don't want to share concrete data to all instances of `item` directive, I can't use broadcasting messages for the same reason.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: You can do `$scope.$emit()` from the child directive and the message only goes to its parent.

Comment: @Chandermani can you provide a simple example?

Comment: In the child controller, on the injected scope just do `$scope.$emit()`

Comment: provide better example ...not clear what issue really is